# Google Chrome extension is not working few laptops

Tags: reactjs, sockets, google-chrome-extension, websocket, fastapi

we have created a google chrome extension and the package unloaded localy. the extension is working 90% of users and it's not working for 10% of users. the extension is not communicating with backend so we are not getting backend logs. I have done the inspection on the browser I got this API error.

```
app.bundle.js:234692 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/sockjs-node' failed:
WebsocketClient @ app.bundle.js:234692
initSocket @ app.bundle.js:235077
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.js:235096
```

it's saying localhost but we have given the server IP address. The extension is working for 90% of user.
the extension is built with FastAPI and ReactJS
backend is in AWS EC2 (FastAPI)
the frontend (reactJS) is local package.

let me know anyone have solution for this issue

Comment: What's not working? What is it supposed to do and what does it do? Any error messages? Do the laptops have an internet connection? Where do you create the WS connection in code? It's really hard to find the problem here.

Comment: So are you communicating with the server with wss://example.com:4000 ? With a library fastAPI ? Or is this a debug / hmr thing that want to open a socket...

Comment: the extension we are created for our internal user who can check the our internal application accessed by whome and manage the user in the internal application.

Comment: user able to work all the activity only this extension is not communicating with backend and getting above error